# java exception handling query

Tags: java, arrays, io, java.util.scanner

```
public class Employee {


public static void main(String[] args) {
   int j=3;
   staples[] stemp = new staples[j];
   String file_name = "d:/personal/11636470/NetBeansProjects/Employee/src/employee/Xanadu.txt";

   throws IOException 

     {

   Scanner s = null;
    try {
        s = new Scanner(
                  new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader("file_name")));

        while (s.hasNext()) 
        {
            System.out.println(s.next());
        }
        } finally 
        {
        if (s != null) 
            {
             s.close();
            }
        }



 try

 {

 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  

 for ( j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            stemp[j] = new staples();

            System.out.print("Enter your name : ");
            stemp[j].setName(reader.readLine());

            System.out.println("Enter your age : "); 
            stemp[j].setAge(Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()));


        }


 for ( j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            System.out.println("Employee number:" + j +" name:"+stemp[j].getName()+" Age:"+stemp[j].getAge() );

        }


 reader.close(); // VERY IMPORTANT TO CLOSE 






 System.out.println("Program ended"); 

 }

 catch(java.io.IOException ex)
 {
     System.out.println("Error is " + ex.getMessage() ); 
 }



}
```

}
}

The problem seems to be simple , i am getting an error in the  "throws IOException" line , is there anything wrong with the try and catch method I implemented?

There are two parts to this code , one is to read the file xanadu.txt and the other is to copy get employee data.Both have try and catch implemetations.

Comment: A bit of reformatting might help, I'm getting confused by line 10

Comment: Yep that code indentation is all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the part You got it totally wrong.

```
try
{
   s = new Scanner((Readable) new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file_name")));
   while (s.hasNext())
      System.out.println(s.next());
   } catch (IOException e)
   {
      // Do the error stuff.
      e.printStackTrace();
   } finally
   {
      // Do it anyway. If error happens or not.
      if (s != null)
         s.close();
   }
}
```

and that `throws IOException` is placed in wrong place, it should be placed here:

`public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {`

In that case you would not need any try, catch blocks - you simply pass that exception to overlaying method(in your case you would not need to worry about it) to let it handle thrown exception, but if you want to handle exceptions with try, catch block you will not need that.

Answer (score 1):

throws clause is valid on the method declaration and not inside the method body.

Comment: so you are  saying that the throws IOException should be placed elsewhere ?

Comment: Yes, it should be `public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {`. The main method can be declared as throwing the exception.

Comment: Or you can catch that exception in your first try block as Marcin described.